# Get_Users Orderby Page

Tags: order, users

I've been trying to fix a sorting issue using the codex for `get_users()`, but I can't seem to get it working.

The codex shows that I can set `'orderby' => 'post_count'`, but I want to change this so that it orders by page count. It seems like it should be something that's easy to change (`page_count`?), but it doesn't work.

Can someone please advise me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`WP_User_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query) and the `has_published_posts` parameter to limit results to users who have published the specified post type(s).

[`get_users()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_users/) is just a wrapper for `WP_User_Query()`.

> `has_published_posts` (boolean / array) - Pass an array of post types
>   to filter results to users who have published posts in those post
>   types. `true` is an alias for all public post types. Default is
>   `null`.

Here's a basic example of a User Query for users who have published a page post type:

```
// Set up arguments for query.
$args = [
    'has_published_posts' => [ 'page' ], 
    'orderby' => 'post_count',
    'order' => 'DESC',
];

// Create the WP_User_Query object
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

// Get results.
$users = $user_query->get_results();

// Check for results
if ( ! empty( $users ) ) {
    echo '<ul>' . PHP_EOL;

    // Loop through each author.
    foreach ( $users as $user ) {
        // Get all the user's data.
        $user_info = get_userdata( $user->ID );
        echo "\t" . '<li>' .
            '<em>' . __( 'User ID: ', 'text-domain' ) . esc_html( $user->ID ) . '</em> ' .
                esc_html( $user_info->first_name ) . ' ' .
                esc_html( $user_info->last_name ) .
        '</li>' . PHP_EOL;
    }

    echo '</ul>' . PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo __( 'No users found', 'text-domain' );
}
```